# ffibuild generate dll with dependencies

Tags: python, dll, dependencies, ffi, cffi

I´m using CFFI for generating a DLL from python source code. It works well but it depends of python3x.dll and need some .pyd files.
Is it possible to package all dependencies inside the dll or a static library ?